# Does Visual Studio code not hightlight .pug files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pug

Recently changed all my view files from .jade to .pug on my Node app. But when I open the files in Visual Studio code, they are not hightlighted, does VS Code not have syntax highlighting for .pug file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across the same problem. For me the problem only exists when I have the Preview extension installed. Disabling this extension has solved the problem for me.

I've opened an issue to the VS Code Repository: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44713

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was the problem for me too. But using the current version (v1.20) which does not seem to have the same issue even with the extension on

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the latest version of Visual Studio Code installed? Mine (v1.18.1) came with `.pug` support preinstalled, and highlights Pug files without a problem. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) also says that Pug syntax highlighting support is present in VS Code.

Comment: I am using v1.19.1, and all .pug files have no syntax highlight. I will try to install that version and see